# How to retrieve a string element from a list ignoring string spaces in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

simple question.

I have got a string variable called "searchTerm" and a list of strings. How could I retrieve a certain element matching my searchTerm variable ignoring whitespaces. An example of what I've been trying to do with no success:

```
string searchTerm = "The Lord Of The Rings"
List<string> films = new List<string>(){ "Harry Potter", "Avangers", "The Lord  Of The Rings", "Back to the future"};
string film = films.where(film => film.Contains(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

This code is not working. Please understand thatin the films list "The Lord  Of The Rings" string has got two whitespaces after Lord word and searchTerm just has got one space.

I've tried the following with no success:

```
string film = films.where(film => film.Replace(" ","").Contains(searchTerm.Replace(" ",""), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Please could you help me to find a solution? thanks

}

Comment: Why does the title have two spaces? Do you have an option to normalize spaces so that it only has one?

Comment: @JonathanWood nope. Just trying to avoid what users within a webapp might do. They can name things with a bunch of spaces without even knowing that they are adding extra spaces.

Comment: The problem is, a user could enter anything, including spelling mistakes, or differences between grammar "The Avengers" vs "Avengers", you probably should use an api from a movie database, and implement an auto complete and force users to select from that list. Otherwise you're going to have tons of issues with this.

Comment: @BrettJenkins you are right! thanks for sharing your thoughts! 
Actually, I'm working on a more complex app and was just using a simple string list with a couple of film names just to make an easy example. Thank you for your help and you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a simple Regular Expression Replacement and string comparison? [DotNet Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6HMR01)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;                  

string searchterm = "The Lord Of The Rings";
List<string> films = new List<string> { "Harry Potter", "Avangers", "The Lord  Of The Rings", "Back to the future"};
string film = films
.FirstOrDefault(f => string.Equals(Regex.Replace(f, "\\s", ""), Regex.Replace(searchterm, "\\s", ""), StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :) this works